# I have two files. I want to list the content of one text file which are not in the other text file

Tags: linux

For example,

Content of a text file named ppcc.txt are:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818624|2000018
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817904|5098596
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234908279|5093267
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234908023|VOIPBurn
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234909392|VOIPBurn
```

And the content of another file named pcs.txt are:

```
234818947|1754261815|20370101000000
234809110|358155618|20370101000000
234809417|1385298890|20361231230000
234908023|1381142974|20171124205011
234909392|358155618|20370101000000
```

I am searching by 234 number, and I want my output to be saved in another text file as Result.txt with the following content:

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234818624|2000018
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234817904|5098596
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|234908279|5093267
```

Comment: Which programming language? You included `linux`in the tags - do you want someone to tell you how to do this at the command line?

Comment: I recommend formatting your code.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next} !($2 in a)' pcs.txt ppcc.txt
```

We are reading two files, first `pcs.txt`, then `ppcc.txt`. Explanation of the program:

```
# Set input and output field delimiter to |
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}

# As long as FNR (record number in current input file) and 
# NR (overall record number) are equals we are reading the 
# first file - pcs.txt
FNR==NR{
    # Store the value of the first column in as a key in
    # an array "a"
    a[$1]=1
    # Don't process any further blocks. Continue with the 
    # next line of input
    next
}

# This expression is only executed on lines of ppcc.txt
# If the array "a" doesn't not contain the second column
# as a key, print it.
!($2 in a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot hek2mgl. Your answer is very useful

Comment: if I look at this command in the other way round(to remove "!" in the command) such that I want to print the data values that are common with the two files pcs.txt and ppcc.txt, hope this command would be appropriate: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next} ($2 in a)' pcs.txt ppcc.txt